# Failed to load a resource with error net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: html, node.js, express

I'm getting the above error when running my index.html that seems not to locate the some dependant source files. Here is my file structure:

```
-**web-client** (*parent folder*)
       -**js** (*child folder*)
              simple.helper.js (*inside js folder*)
       - **model** (*child folder*)
              teamModel.js (*inside model folder*)
              mathModel.js (*inside model folder*)
       - **view** (*child folder*)
              view.js (*inside view folder*)
       - **views** (*child folder*)
              index.html (*inside views folder*)
       - **controller** (*child folder*)
              mainController.js  (*inside controller folder*)
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>WebApp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.6.2/css/bulma.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bulma-min.css">

    <script src="js/simple-helper.js"></script>
    <script src="model/teamModel.js"></script>
    <script src="model/mathModel.js"></script>
    <script src="web-client/view/teamView.js"></script>
    <script src="/mathServer/view/TalView.js"></script>
    <script src="/web-client/controller/mainController.js"></script>
    
   <script>
```

Errors

```
http://127.0.0.1:3002/js/simple-helper.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
127.0.0.1/:18 GET http://127.0.0.1:3002/model/teamModel.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
127.0.0.1/:19 GET http://127.0.0.1:3002/model/mathModel.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
127.0.0.1/:20 GET http://127.0.0.1:3002/web-client/view/teamView.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
127.0.0.1/:21 GET http://127.0.0.1:3002/mathServer/view/TalView.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
127.0.0.1/:22 GET http://127.0.0.1:3002/web-client/controller/mainController.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Have you tried this? https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: Not really, let me try it out. I'll get back if it works.

Comment: How should the path appear in script in index.html "src=????"

Comment: Should be something like `/js/simple-helper.js`. Try it out